# Parsing an UTF-16 stream and recovering from encoding errors

Tags: unicode, utf-16

I'm implementing a simple line/column counting algorithm, for counting "graphemes" in a UTF-16 stream. As usual, handling errors is the tricky part.

E.g. how to handle a *low surrogate* or a *combining character* following a new line?

How does the standard propose dealing with this? Abort the parse? try to resynchronize? if so, how?

I know one possible answer is "RTFM", but given the sheer size of the standard, that task is a bit daunting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a low surrogate without a corresponding high surrogate, then you have an invalid UTF-16 sequence. The standard doesn't mandate a particular error-handing strategy, but gives you the option of either ignoring it, aborting the parse, or replacing it with `U+FFFD` (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER) – whatever makes sense for your application (see the last paragraph of [Section 2.7](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode8.0.0/ch02.pdf)). A stray surrogate will be captured by [rules GB4 and GB5](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#GB4) if you simply ignore it.

Stray combining marks are perfectly valid, and don't require any special treatment. They will be captured by [rule GB9](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#GB9).